# Запрос в sql не отправляется

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin

Ничего не отображается в sql, ошибок тоже не выдаёт.

```
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO plant (name, email, course, code, pass) VALUES ($name, $email, $course, $code, $status)";
    header ('Location: orders.php');
    exit();
}
?>
<title>Заказ курсов</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form method="get">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"/>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
      <p><b>Тип услуги которую вы хотите заказать:</b><Br>
           <input type="radio" name="course" value="Высшее очное образование"> Высшее очное образование<Br>
           <input type="radio" name="course" value="Среднее очное образование"> Среднее очное образование<Br>
           <input type="radio" name="course" value="Высшее очное образование[БЮДЖЕТ]"> Высшее очное образование[БЮДЖЕТ]<Br>
           <input type="radio" name="course" value="Среднее очное образование[БЮДЖЕТ]"> Среднее очное образование[БЮДЖЕТ]<Br>
           <input type="radio" name="course" value="Высшее очное образование[БЮДЖЕТ][ОБЩЕЖИТИЕ]"> Высшее очное образование[БЮДЖЕТ][ОБЩЕЖИТИЕ]<Br>   
      </p>
      <input type="text" name="code" placeholder="Ваш промокод"/>
      <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Зарегистрировать"></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: А кто будет квотировать строковые литералы?

Comment: я банан ничего не знаю

Comment: *ошибок тоже не выдаёт.* даёт. Только Вы их не выводите. Посмотрите в мануале, что надо добавить в код, чтобы их увидеть.

Answer (score 0):

SQL это язык запросов в базу данных (например в базу данных MySQL). Вы написали SQL-запрос, но в базу данных его не отправили. То есть, вы просто создали строчку. Так не работает.

В программировании нет никакой магии -- всё откуда-то берётся, а не возникает по волшебству. Чтобы получить ответ от базы данных, надо отправить ей запрос. В документации есть описание всех необходимых для работы с базой данных функций. Если вы работаете с MySQL, то вероятно вам будет проще начать с изучения расширения mysqli, для него есть [руководство](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.php). Когда почувствуете себя уверенно, то можете попробовать другое решение для работы с базами данных (не только MySQL) -- [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php). PDO более популярное среди разработчиков решение.